# Select2 css problems

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Theme css select design is broken when I add select2 how do I fix this?

```js
$("select").select2();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<select class="select2 form-control">
  <option selected="">Var (Kedi/Köpek)</option>
  <option>Yok</option>
</select>
```

[image: Original Select]

[image: select 2]

Comment: @Tausif [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/kfkswLu.png) I have not tried this.

Comment: "*css select design is broken*" - can you be more specific?  It looks like a select2 to me.  Select2 isn't a bootstrap component, so won't look like bootstrap unless you add some extra styles.

Comment: How you add the bootstrap theme will depend on which version of boostrap you're using and which version of select2 you're using.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to do a code for the select2. I think you are missing the **multiple** keyword in the select element. I have tried with the **multiple** keyword. You can refer to the same.

**Head Section:**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/select2@4.0.13/dist/js/select2.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("select").select2();
    });
</script>
```

**HTML Code:**

```
 <select multiple id="e1" style="width: 300px;">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>
        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: `style="width: 300px;"` help to solve the with style issue